# Why is `g` part of the app context rather than the request context?

Tags: python, flask

Flask seems to always add and remove the app context and request context together.  Why are they separate and why is the `g` object part of the app context and not the request context?

Comment: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/appcontext/#purpose-of-the-application-context

Comment: @ Martijn Pieters I can't understand the doc ,mybe i need some examlpes to understand the appcontext and the g

Answer (score 0):

An app context can be created without creating a request context.  This is useful for launching a Python shell with the app "activated".  It's also useful for using extensions outside a request (such as when using an app factory and doing some setup).  Nothing about the `g` object is specific to a request, so it is made available at the app level instead.